# Synonyms maintenance: How to delete synonyms?

Tags: curl, solr, retrieve-and-rank, watson

We are trying to delete synonyms using the following curl command.

```
curl -v -X DELETE -u "username":"password" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/CLUSTER/solr/COLLECTION/schema/analysis/synonyms/english/mad"
```

We are getting as a result:

```
 *   Trying 158.85.132.88...
 * TCP_NODELAY set
 * Connected to gateway.watsonplatform.net (158.85.132.88) port 443 (#0)
 * ALPN, offering h2
 * ALPN, offering http/1.1
 * Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
 *   CAfile: D:\NB16647\Desktop\curl-7.50.3-win64-mingw\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
   CApath: none
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-GCM-SHA384
 * ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
 * Server certificate:
 *  subject: C=US; ST=New York; L=Armonk; O=International Business Machines Corporation; CN=*.watsonplatform.net
 *  start date: Jan 30 00:00:00 2015 GMT
 *  expire date: Jan 29 23:59:59 2018 GMT
 *  subjectAltName: host "gateway.watsonplatform.net" matched cert's "*.watsonplatform.net"
 *  issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
 *  SSL certificate verify ok.
 * Server auth using Basic with user 'USERNAME'
 > DELETE /retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/CLUSTER/solr/COLLECTION/schema/analysis/synonyms/english/mad HTTP/1.1
 > Host: gateway.watsonplatform.net
 > Authorization: Basic MDkzYzg2ZTEtM2UwMy00NWM2LThmNWMtNDVkN2RlNzM1ZTQyOnhteGV2UzBPTmlsWQ==
 > User-Agent: curl/7.50.3
 > Accept: */*
 >
 < HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
 < X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
 < Connection: Keep-Alive
 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 < Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2016 16:04:51 GMT
 < Allow: HEAD,POST,GET,OPTIONS
 < Server: -
 < Set-Cookie: Watson-DPAT=gYvN5yLQe3JmVm1d496bA85NFBCd4bWgyvYv8YoV%2FpOlj6ZOsGxVcKZUaR9SUb5L6Ch5SYrSzIe2BSZCk0VvRLQW%2BKeBpz%2B2lpCfmiYvvXWnzah6GmQMnd4AuH3e0hJOb6SORsjOAggLiMweaA6khvQLxqgU2RR5%2FEfemnk6SP3p04YUMHUQRRo4orabJuANouni4RyJJXuCwotrpbNnNwL%2FyFVT2KlxusaLe5V1gxoCsKonKJTzaxtKJDxetwqZ20pPaZ2wZkY4eA9pYlBb6T5gN9bOsHPhxGCtpATG6bK5MpVfHpLi4ae9V2oliLbNqq7VQo%2FRvtHk5%2B1FUmLmY3pYX975Yni0LGkcCnjkbSxNvdelq1PJa3MIAAKf7oqQIx25Efj8gEaKhqHU3i5S8IPj5Xqoh6dwFoL9kN5%2Fxy8P3u3Hbl9iZHT%2B%2FcoTBwxI6IBYZ2b9u8VfTB8cQ%2Fm4RktQMWJeDqqF%2BOwcuGx9dmS6GcU66Xab87Fu52zE8aZzULOgS4maozhMKLOt5v9j1A7ZkVAKLXSiWCysVI0aHjcjBjGbKJERx28JuRQq4v3lRGQ2ujMQGKq1cnEhyxYWXcvj5CMIGQWT8%2Bltt5VddJOmE%2BgdzBnRT6MNkB0qQZx7JkoJ%2BJ6TKu7NSroOx5zV0FCilK10uEoVxSe8UUMfrINNxKNmEWc7cJ9zrceou4q4RBVNzgK5A9PrRn%2FiE7A8grHTk9nuqIbhjuYLNO09gFzzgJQ6qVNkVRX0crJJldAMZ4gxZY1zSUWDqG5bxoTo82FrLM0G%2FttJIMNBuFNk4Rhyagp07DnP87vURU%2BEu1MNYpuZ%2BLPEzRd61fAvWNam%2FQhBWqQ0u2mQr6KoPJu5eay0pQL87nJAT%2BiiZBG74FOAmC5FICGJ0HV%2BprnDXOMMr5PWdoZgSiSfsHOFkDrZ%2B8ysff%2FrZxQCKrYiWR8enI0ryg8klGKsC67HJuC0i9Dpq3AmAvfcjG0j5ppKc3gBzSUaQNCquBv%2FcaonuSdwwuh4pAj%2B2%2BUSjU9ncVke8dlNlmuZTXlYW65Bvod1CUuIPUPPrvUi1BFnS6NBdHPKZqbEZQ8DeoTHZ0s%3D; path=/retrieve-and-rank/api; secure; HttpOnly
 < X-Client-IP: 88.157.199.114
 < X-Global-Transaction-ID: 260709032
 < Content-Type:
 < X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID: gateway-dp02-260709032
 <
 * Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
 * Connection #0 to host gateway.watsonplatform.net left intact
```

The message `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` means that we cannot perform this delete action. This is true or the curl command isn't correct?

By the way, do you know if it's possible to perform a 'delete all' operation/action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `curl` request is looking good to me actually.
Unfortunately Solr doesn't provide you means to delete all synonyms. For more details you could see the following [Managed Resources](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources) wiki page.

From what I see the problem is related to the proxy part of the whole end-to-end path. Here is why:

```
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
< Allow: HEAD,POST,GET,OPTIONS
```

Which means that allowed methods are: `HEAD`, `POST`, `GET`, `OPTIONS` only.
You need to tweak Watson or DW (whatever underlying framework is) is order to allow `DELETE` methods for the Solr's base path.

As a proof for that you could test synonyms delete by calling Solr directly instead of using proxy / orchestration layer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify **_schema_analysis_synonyms_en.json** file in a **/cores/../managed/**. Restart is needed.